# Parse JSON into Object Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, object

I have created an array that contains objects, some of the properties are also objects. I have converted it to JSON successfully and need to convert it back into an array of the objects, or somehow pull the correct data from the correct index of the JSON object.

**Update**

This is a sample of what I get when I run it through JSON.parse:

```
[{"Result":"Fail","Method":"T97E-v1","Beam1":{"BeamAge":"1","WidthUpper":1,"WidthCenter":1,"WidthLower":1,"WidthAverage":1,"DepthRight":1,"DepthCenter":1,"DepthLeft":1,"DepthAverage":1,"MaxLoad":1,"FS":18,"PSI":"18.00000","BreakOutside":"No"},"Beam2":{"BeamAge":"","WidthUpper":null,"WidthCenter":null,"WidthLower":null,"WidthAverage":null,"DepthRight":null,"DepthCenter":null,"DepthLeft":null,"DepthAverage":null,"MaxLoad":null,"FS":null,"PSI":"NaN"},"WaitForCuring":"No","AverageOfBeams":"NaN"}]
```

**Update 2**

Here is the code around what I'm doing:

```
try {
    localStorage["flexuralStrengthSamples"] = JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(t97Samples));
    var parsedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage["flexuralStrengthSamples"]);

    console.log(parsedObject);                    
    console.log(parsedObject[0].Beam1.MaxLoad);            
} catch (err) {
    alert(err.message);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what about some data example? or maybe some code youv'e tried already? stack is not a place to ask for code, but to ask concrete questions.

Comment: Maybe if you tell about the language you're using you can help us to help you. If you're using javascript the problem doesn't exist because JSON is the string serialization of a javascript object. So with the JSON.parse you should be OK.

Comment: @PanamaJack I've had nothing but failed and broken code. I update to show what I get when parsing the JSON.

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Explain exactly what result you are expecting.

Comment: To either convert it back into an array of objects, as it was before, or to be able to pull values from specific keys in specific indices of the string.

Comment: @CodyHarness, can you provide js fiddle what you try? or want do? and where is problem?

Comment: @CodyHarness Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/czk21fou/

Comment: I added my code. Why are you and cricket getting output but I'm just getting errors?

Comment: @CodyHarness, why you do `stringify` twice? one is enough. Also simple logic: if you twice convert to string, so and parse you also should twice. But anyway, enough call `stringify` once

Comment: @Grundy I'm definitely facepalming right now. That's been my error this whole time. If you want to submit that as an answer then I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: @CodyHarness, i think better mark this question as simple typo :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason: You are stringyfying twice before storing it in localstorage

```
try {
     localStorage["flexuralStrengthSamples"] = (JSON.stringify(t97Samples)); //Stringify only once, since localstorage values needs to be string
     var parsedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage["flexuralStrengthSamples"]); // should give the original object.


   console.log(parsedObject[0].Beam1.MaxLoad); // Since parsedObject is still string, this was failing. Now should work fine           
} catch (err) {
   alert(err.message);
}
```

See the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/pnb88p4s/

Answer (score 1):

You can parse JSON using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

**Update**
Here is a sample of your data from `JSON.parse()`.

`[{"Result":"Fail","Method":"T97E-v1","Beam1":{"BeamAge":"1","WidthUpper":1,"WidthCenter":1,"WidthLower":1,"WidthAverage":1,"DepthRight":1,"DepthCenter":1,"DepthLeft":1,"DepthAverage":1,"MaxLoad":1,"FS":18,"PSI":"18.00000","BreakOutside":"No"}}]`

In order to get at your data, you need to use bracket-notation for arrays and dot-notation for objects. So, let `data` be equal to that JSON Array, then you can do `data[0].Result`, which is `"Fail"`, or `data[0].Beam1.MaxLoad`, which is `1`.

Comment: I've tried that. It always gives me the error "Cannot read property 'MaxLoad' of undefined."

Comment: `data[0].Beam1.MaxLoad` prints 1 in the console for me

Comment: I added my code. It seems anyone on this question and any others that I've been to can get output, but I never can.